# Button variable turns to null after calling method

Tags: android, android-resources

In my mainactivity I have the following snip

MainActivity.class

```
private Button btnx10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Button btnx10=(Button)findViewById(R.id.MainCOPbtn);
    DrawLines();
}


private void drawLines(){
   float centerYOnImage1=btnx10.getHeight()/2;
}
```

I'm trying to access the button that is created in the `onCreate()` method from the method `drawLines()`
i.e. in the same class `MainActivity.class` but outside of this method.

When I am trying to access the button in the `drawlines()`method it's value is null.

How can I access the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have declared the Button in **Scope of Method** `onCreate()`

```
Button btnx10=(Button)findViewById(R.id.MainCOPbtn);
```

and you are trying to access it outside of the method `onCreate()`, that makes it **inaccessible** outside of this method.

Just make the reference on class level (Globally) and use the same Reference in `onCreate()` method.

you can do this:-

```
private Button btnx10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    btnx10 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.MainCOPbtn);
    DrawLines();
}


private void drawLines(){
   float centerYOnImage1 = btnx10.getHeight()/2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to 
`btnx10= findViewById(R.id.MainCOPbtn);`

You are casting `Button` in the declaration which makes global variable inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

Remove local declaration of `Button` again.

Just use `btnx10=(Button)findViewById(R.id.MainCOPbtn);` in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

> You are declaring `Button btnx10` twice. Remove the local declaration.
>   You should declare outside the method, and define inside the method.

```
Class MainActivity...
private Button btnx10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    btnx10=(Button)findViewById(R.id.MainCOPbtn); //MINOR CORRECTION IN THIS LINE
    DrawLines()    
}

private void drawLines() {
     float centerYOnImage1=btnx10.getHeight()/2;
}
```